# Name collision of class function and non-class function

Tags: c++, class, networking

So, in C++ I have a class Vote which has a send function to send the vote over the network. This send function in the class Vote, makes use of the send function from sys/socket.h. When I compile, I get errors that basically say it's using Vote::send rather than sys/socket.h::send within Vote::send. How do I resolve this name conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [scope resolution operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31.aspx) (`::`) to refer to a `send()` function from global scope, like:

```
void Vote::send() {
        ::send(...); // Calls global send(). 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different things that you can do. You can qualify the call:

```
void Vote::send() {
   ::send(...);
}
```

or you can bring the namespace level function into scope by means of a *using declaration*:

```
void Vote::send() {
    using ::send;
    send(...);
}
```

or, if it is a namespace function and it lives in the same namespace than the `Vote` class, you could also provide a local declaration, although I would avoid local function declarations as it is far easier to get the wrong signature:

```
void Vote::send() {
   int send(int, const void*, size_t, int);
   send(...);
}
```